# Partial Class Mocking

Tags: c++, hippomocks

I want to use hippomocks to mock a method in a class.  That method is called by another method in the same class.  As in...

```
class Foo {
public:
Foo() {}
  virtual ~Foo() {}

  virtual string getName() {
    return "Joe";
  }

  virtual void print() {
    std::cout<<"Name is "<<getName()<<std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cout<<"test mocking classes()..."<<std::endl;

  MockRepository mocks;
  Foo* pFoo = mocks.Mock<Foo>();
  mocks.ExpectCall(pFoo, Foo::getName).Return("John");
  pFoo->print();

  return 0;
}
```

test mocking classes()...

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'HippoMocks::NotImplementedException'
  what():  Function called without expectation!

Any idea why i can't mock a method like this?

The example on http://hippomocks.com/Main_Page looks almost the same as mine, so i think this should be supported?

Thanks, 
G

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from how hippomocks works is that it is overriding all of the virtual functions in your class, so the exception is probably caused by calling unexpected `print()`

Comment: i tried compiling the example on their 'Main_Page' and im' getting the same exception.  Thats why im' not sure if i'm doing something incorrectly or there's a bug in their code.